# Stop at a certain point on a horizontal scrolling page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to accomplish a carousel type of functionality with forms.

I use an `ng-repeat` to loop through each set of form values to be displayed on each form field.

The width of horizontal scrollable area:

```
width of form * amount of forms
```

[image: IMAGE EXAMPLE]

Currently I am able to scroll horizontally but ideally I would like to be able to scroll and stop at each form and take into account the index of the current form displayed.

Is there a way to detect that when scrolling, if there is an existing div, stop and display the form rather than freely scrolling? Or possibly a better way of handling this?

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach. You shouldn't want to _stop_ at certain position. You want to calculate that position in advance then use an animation on scrollLeft to the calculated position.

Comment: @marekful I will try this approach now. Will report back on the results, good or not.

Comment: These are good reading, even though they don't answer your question: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/ and https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scroll-snap-using-css--cms-30333

Comment: I recently accomplished this using slightly different method using 2 "frames", basically they would be used for the animation (one would have the old content, one with the new, JS would scroll the parent element of the frames all the way over with a animation to show the new content, Then JS would replace the old content with the new and do a `scrollto()` (no animation) to the frame that originally had the old content. Then process was reset). JS also handled all the new content.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `Scroll Snapping` property is exactly what you are looking for. the only issue is that it does not work consistently across browsers. Here is how it works.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

There are all types of options on how to use it. For more information take a look at this awesome article.
https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/